# How to change req.body during the request in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http-post, api-design

I am trying to use a Node.js payment SDK on my API (running on Express). The problem is, after validating the card details and beginning the transaction, an OTP is sent to the user from his/her bank. The payment process depends on this otp to complete the payment. How do I allow the user to pass this in while the request is ongoing (using req.body), or is there a better way to do this?

For reference purposes, please check [this link](https://developer.flutterwave.com/docs/nodejs-sdk#section-card-charge).

Answer (score 0):

You could use body-parser, a middle ware package meant for these kind of problems.

https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html

https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Here are the links on express' docs and npm.